# GMSGeocoder geocoder - reverseGeocodeCoordinate - suddenly returns response in English

Tags: ios, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

My App in Production mode. Suddenly it returns response in English - started today morning(**Instead of hebrew**).

```
 [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:
```

I am using this code in main.m:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"he",@"he-IL"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Worked wonderful in the last year, what happened?!

Tnx, Dan

Comment: It seems to be a bug on Google side. It was reported in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64988249 and current state is Accepted.

Comment: Seems like google fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I have the exactly same issue. as a workaround we've switched to CLGeocoder.